# Working with multiple parameter options purchase() purchase(2)

Tags: python-3.x

The program is a virtual soda machine, Im having trouble with the purchase method. In the cases I need to pass there is a purchase() case which assumes one can is being bought, and a purchase(2) case  where 2 cans are being bought.

I believe in python3 you cannot make multiple methods with the same name that have separate parameters.

```
def purchase(self):  
    do stuff  
    return otherstuff
```

> TypeError: purchase() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1):

You can have a parameter with default value

```
def purchase(self, amount=1):  
    do stuff  
    return otherstuff
```

This way, when you call `purchase()` which will be the equivalent of `purchase(1)` and you can use the parameter and call `purchase(2)`.